# Tikz 3D Plots not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I wanted to get into some 3D plotting with Tikz 3D. I just wanted to learn the basics first and I copied an example to see if everything worked correctly. But then this happend:
[image]

I know it's probably an easy fix but I don't know what I did wrong because I just copied an example. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1cm, right=1cm, top=1cm]{geometry}


\pagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width = 13cm}

\author{}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \section{Tikz 3D}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, scale = 1]
      \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I also got an error message:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome! In LaTex, often, *only* the first error is significant. Here, the compiler tells you that the file `tikz-3dplot.sty` does not know the command `\usetikzlibrary`, basically because `tikz` is not loaded. Interchange your first two `\usepackage` commands (i.e., load Ti*k*Z before `tikz-3dplot`).

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works now. I dindn't know that the order of the packages mattered.

Comment: Well, arguably `tikz-3dplot` should have a `RequirePackage` command that makes the order not relevant (like `pgfplots`), but maybe there are reasons for not using it. But yes, sometimes the loading order of packages does indeed matter.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the order of those two `\usepackage`:

```
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

For whatever reason, the `tikz-3dplot` does not issue a `RequirePackage{tikz}`, so you need to load it *after* loading Ti*k*Z (or `pgfplots`, which does declare the dependency, and so it loads Ti*k*Z automatically if not already loaded). So you have to say:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
```

How to notice that? If you look at the *first* error (ignore the other ones, they are a secondary effect, it happens a lot with LaTeX), you can see that the error is because while compiling the (system) file

```
...texlive2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot.sty
```

LaTeX says it does not know what `\usetikzlibrary` is, and this can happen only because `tikz` is not loaded at that point.

Comment: At least, the manual's section 1.2.1 instructs to load packages `tikz` and `ifthen` before `tikz-3dplot`. The author was at least aware of it (and maybe simply didn't know about `\RequirePackage`).